# R searching for minimum date across columns based on a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, min, lubridate

I have the following data frame with several date variables.

```
    x <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4), date = structure(c(18611, 
16801, 16801, 17532), class = "Date"), s1 = c(0, 1, 1, NA), date1 = structure(c(17880, 
16450, 16416, NA), class = "Date"), s2 = c(0, 0, 1, NA), date2 = structure(c(17880, 
NA, 15869, NA), class = "Date"), DN = structure(c(18611, 15869, 
15869, NA), class = "Date")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I would like to compare `date1` and `date2` and generate `DN` as the minimum of the two dates based on the conditions in `case_when`. I am currently using this code:

```
x <- mutate(date = as.Date(date),
           date1 =  as.Date(date1),
           date2 =  as.Date(date2),
           DN = case_when(
               s1 == 1 | s2 == 1 ~ min(date1, date2, na.rm = T),
               s1 == 0 | s2 == 0 ~ date,
               is.na(s1) & is.na(s2) ~ NA_real_
           ))
```

However, I get a strange result !! For `id = 2` the value of `DN` is taken from `id = 3`, which I can not understand !!

Any ideas?
Thanks in forward

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pmin` to select the first date of the assigned columns. You can use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
  mutate(DN = case_when(
    s1 == 1 | s2 == 1 ~ pmin(date1, date2, na.rm = T),
    s1 == 0 | s2 == 0 ~ date,
    is.na(s1) & is.na(s2) ~ NA_real_
  ))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 7
     id date          s1 date1         s2 date2      DN        
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <date>     <date>    
1     1 2020-12-15     0 2018-12-15     0 2018-12-15 2020-12-15
2     2 2016-01-01     1 2015-01-15     0 NA         2015-01-15
3     3 2016-01-01     1 2014-12-12     1 2013-06-13 2013-06-13
4     4 2018-01-01    NA NA            NA NA         NA
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add `rowwise()` (i.e. grouping by rows) you will get the required row-minimum:

```
x %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date),
         date1 =  as.Date(date1),
         date2 =  as.Date(date2),
         DN = case_when(
           s1 == 1 | s2 == 1 ~ pmin(date1, date2, na.rm = T),
           s1 == 0 | s2 == 0 ~ date,
           is.na(s1) & is.na(s2) ~ NA_real_
         ))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Why do I need to add this in this case specifically? I usually do not and `mutate` delivers corrects results.

Comment: Beside, when I run your code I get the following error:
`Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `DN`.
i `DN = case_when(...)`.
i no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
i The warning occurred in row 4. `

Comment: I assume that `case_when` uses the whole column vector when evaluating the `min` function, hence `rowwise` ensures that it only uses the correct id-rows to take the minimum. Using `pmin` you will get rid of the warning message. See here for a similar question to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53084598/row-wise-min-on-right-hand-when-using-dplyrcase-when?rq=1